# Blackberry how to empty tablemodel

Tags: blackberry, abstracttablemodel

I have a tableadapter implementation in my application extended from TableModelAdapter and for some reason I want to make tablemodel empty (delete all data inside model) and refill it with new values
is it posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your underlying data as needed and then call `TableModel.modelReset()` to notify the `TableView` that a big change has occured.